# Demonstrate whether Range is not empty in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

How to write the code to demonstrate that the Range from C5 to C24 is not empty then will be counted in countFile?

```
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Path As String
Dim count As Integer
Dim countFile As Integer
Dim Folder As String

FolderPath = Range("B2")
Path = FolderPath & "\*.xls"
Filename = Dir(Path)

If Folder = vbNullString Then
    Range("C2").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else
    Range("C2").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If

Do While Filename <> ""
   count = count + 1
   Filename = Dir()
Loop

countFile = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C5:C24") NotIsEmpty)
If count = 6 * countFile - countFile + 1 Then
    Range("C2").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else
    Range("C2").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula `COUNTIF(C5:C21,"<>")` it worked in Excel.

```
countFile = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C5:C24") ,"<>")
```